# execute multiple object methods parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I want to run create 4 objects by pass different arguments and calling the method I want to get return value. I want to execute this methods parallel.

```
Rank rg = new Rank(para);
Rank rb = new Rank(para);
Rank ry = new Rank(para);
Rank ra = new Rank(para);

sr.class1Rank = rg.GetPosition();
sr.class2Rank = rb.GetPosition();
sr.class3Rank = ry.GetPosition();
sr.class4Rank = ra.GetPosition();
```

I don't have I idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Task Paralleism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => DoSomeWork(), () => DoSomeOtherWork());
```

In your case:

```
  Parallel.Invoke(
        () => rg.GetPosition(),
        () => rb.GetPosition(),
        () => ry.GetPosition()
        () => ra.GetPosition());
```