# Executing 2 methods parallel using C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have a scenario to monitor the state of the ui test. If the test is running more than `30` mins, stop the test run and start with another test. Here is the code developed to simulate the same. I apologies if i am duplicating here.

Reference: [execute mutiple object methods parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472232/execute-mutiple-object-methods-parallel)

Here is the sample program that, developed in line with my requirement.I request experts to comment on my approach and suggest me the best of it.

```
<code>

namespace ParallelTasksExample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static Stopwatch testMonitor;
        private static int timeElapsed;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(() => PrintNumber(), () => MonitorSequence());
        }

        private static void PrintNumber()
        {
            testMonitor = new Stopwatch();
            testMonitor.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                timeElapsed = testMonitor.Elapsed.Seconds;
                Console.WriteLine("Running since :" + timeElapsed + " seconds");
            }
        }

        private static void MonitorSequence()
        {
            while (timeElapsed < 25)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed :" + timeElapsed + " seconds");
            }
            testMonitor.Stop();
            testMonitor.Reset();
            Console.WriteLine("Test has taken more then 25 seconds. Closing the current test sequence initiated.");
        }
    }
}
</code>
```

I am facing an issue, when the actual code developed based on the above example.
task 1 is completed and task 2 is in progress. Meanwhile task 1 is waiting for task2 to finish. How can we make both tasks are independent?

Comment: Stack Overflow is mainly for problems to be solved. If your code is doing what you expect it to do and you want an expert opinion how to improve it,  head over to the guys at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am sorry, i have not included my question.

Comment: What test framework or test runner are you using? It may have this behaviour built in.

Comment: HP UFT is a tool. This is my C# console application to monitor the same. Task 1 is launch the tool and run it. Task 2 is monitor the run, if it is exceed 30 seconds, get the object of Task 1 and pass "Stop" command and instruct Task 1 to start another test.